# Get EF generated SQL query with variables values already plugged in ("p__linq__n")

Tags: entity-framework, linq-to-entities, iqueryable

Calling `.ToString()` to a `IQueryable` will return the generated SQL query with the values of the variables not plugged in yet. So there are these `p__linq__n` with `n=0, 1, 2...` in the query itself.

eg: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x = p__linq__0`

**Question:** Is it possible to get the final query? with the values of these variables already plugged into the query?

eg: `SELECT * FROM foo WHERE x = 6`

Answer (score 2):

EF parametrizes queries to avoid Sql injections attacks and to be able to cache and re-use the same query even if some values change. To see parameters you can use the logging feature introduced in EF6. See [this](http://blog.oneunicorn.com/2013/05/08/ef6-sql-logging-part-1-simple-logging/) blogpost series for more details.

Comment: I want the final query "ready to use". ie: a string that I can copy-paste to the database and execute with `<ENTER>`. I know I can check the parameter values with the logging feature but I still have to plug those values to the query

Comment: Probably use Sql Analyzer. I don't think you will be able to get what you want directly from EF.